# All the cell are same

Tags: ios, uitableview

I tried to implement a table in storyboard in xcode5.
When doing in story board i am not able to get the result.
I tried to use the following code in the storyboard.
Can someone spot what is wrong with this code?
The output shows all the cell same. How i can separate each cell with different objects in the array?

```
temp=[[HomeDetails alloc]init];
array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
homecell=[[HomeCell alloc]init];

selection.Title=@"Popular";
selection.description=@"ghjggb";
selection.Image=@"PopularLogo.png";

[array addObject:selection];

selection.Title=@"Browse";
selection.description=@"gdfgdgb";
selection.Image=@"BrowseLogo.png";

[array addObject:selection];

selection.Title=@"My Signture";
selection.description=@"gdfgdfgb";
selection.Image=@"MySignatureLogo.png";

[array addObject:selection];
```

I have made the tableviewcell inside the tableview prototype itself.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell1";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell==nil)
{
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
        temp=[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        UILabel *Label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
        Label.text = temp.Title;
        NSLog(@"%d",indexPath.row);
        UIImageView *Image = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:temp.Image];
        UITextField *textfield = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
        textfield.text =temp.description;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding same object "selection" over and over again to an array.
What's more you are editing properties of the same object - which will affect all 3 elements existing in array - because it is same object in memory.

Create new instance each time before setting values.

```
selection = [Selection new]; //this is missing - each time you want to create a new one.
selection.Title=@"My Signture";
selection.description=@"gdfgdfgb";
selection.Image=@"MySignatureLogo.png";
[array addObject:selection];
```